# Split string containing multiple network paths

Tags: c#, regex, path

I have a string which contains multiple network path locations. It could be 2, 3 or any number. I want to split into number of paths. I am using regular expression but I am not getting desired results.

```
string samplePath = "\\Computer1\Folder\Folder \\Computer2\Folder\New Folder \\Computer\New Folder"
```

I cannot split this by using space as delim character as folder name can contain spaces in them.
Here is the regular expression I am using to get my desired result.

```
var pattern = @"^\\{2}[\w-]+(\\{1}(([\w-][\w-\s]*[\w-]+[$$]?)|([\w-][$$]?$)))+";
var matches = Regex.Matches(samplePath, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (var match in matches)
    myCollectionList.Add(match.ToString());
```

What happens after this is that I am getting only one result (first path). Matches count is 1. Where is the problem.

Comment: Why use regex at all? Why not just split by space? Or by " \\" to that matter? It will also be faster in runtime.

Comment: Note that multiple backslashes are valid in a path: C:\path1\\path2\\\filename.txt is equivalent to c:\path1\path2\filename.txt. This can happen when wrongly concatenating paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Regex.Split`

```
string source = @"\\Computer1\Folder\Folder \\Computer2\Folder\New Folder \\Computer\New Folder";

string[] result = Regex.Split(source, @" (?=\\\\)");

    foreach (string a in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

This will print

```
\\Computer1\Folder\Folder  
\\Computer2\Folder\New Folder  
\\Computer\New Folder
```

`@" (?=\\\\)"` is a regular expression that will match a space only when it is followed by two backslashes. `(?=\\\\)` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can **split** it with this regex

```
\s*(?=\\)
```

---

So,it would be like

```
Regex.Split(input,yourRegex);
```